# Prism.Forms: Why navigationService is not singleton?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Hi when I am looking at the implementation of `PrismApplicationBase` I found following piece of code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers all types that are required by Prism to function with the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="containerRegistry"></param>
    protected virtual void RegisterRequiredTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IContainerExtension>(_containerExtension);
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFacade, EmptyLogger>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IApplicationProvider, ApplicationProvider>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IApplicationStore, ApplicationStore>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDependencyService, DependencyService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPageDialogService, PageDialogService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDeviceService, DeviceService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IPageBehaviorFactory, PageBehaviorFactory>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IModuleCatalog, ModuleCatalog>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IModuleManager, ModuleManager>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IModuleInitializer, ModuleInitializer>();
        containerRegistry.Register<INavigationService, PageNavigationService>(NavigationServiceName);
    }
```

we can see that the last registration for the navigation service is **NOT** singleton.

So my two questions are:

1. Why the registration for the `INavigationService` is not singleton like other services ?
2. Why do we assign a name for it (i.e. `NavigationServiceName`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Navigating in a Prism application is conceptually different than standard navigation in Xamarin.Forms. While Xamarin.Forms navigation relies on a Page class instance to navigate, Prism removes all dependencies on Page types to achieve loosely coupled navigation from within a ViewModel. In Prism, the concept of navigating to a View or navigating to a ViewModel does not exist.So INavigationService is not singleton.

Navigate to an experience, or a unique identifier, which represents the target view you wish to navigate to in your application. so you need assgin a name for it.

Comment: The second paragraph does not make sense. What does the naming of the navigation target have to do with the naming of the navigation service?

Comment: I did not understand , why being singleton will stop the serivce from navigating to a viewmodel ?

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7baeb323dbf1610ed05de21a477291194b0f1eb1/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs), you'll notice that the `PageNavigationService` has no state of its own, so there's no *need* to make it a singleton.

One tries to have as few singletons as possible, normally. They introduce overhead, cannot die (sortof an intentional memory leak) and complicate things.

Comment: if it does not have a state of its own , where does it save the stack of pages then? if you see the code of  GoBackInternal it uses `PageUtility` and I think this what keeps track of pages ... 

anyway, regarding the performance and memory leak I really did not get convinced  since the rest of the services are registered as singleton .

Comment: Those other services have a state and need to be singletons. But just by using one of the singletons, you don't become a singleton of your own.To the contrary, if some singleton manages your state for you, you don't need to be a singleton yourself.

Comment: How about the page stack ? isn't that a state ?

Comment: Of course, it's a state, but that state is managed by the `ApplicationProvider`, not the `PageNavigationService`. And the `ApplicationProvider` _is_ a singleton...

Comment: ok good to know , I am working on writing an article , can i get your contact ? i want to show you an issue i get regarding the navigation (and being singleton) maybe you can help me so i can reform the question and you can find the issue , is there a way to share the screen with you ? it is not going to take more than 15 mins