# How to navigate with Prism for Xamarin outside of ViewModel with Tabbed page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a tabbed page with three tabs. I want to *programmatically* select a tab, and then navigate to a new page within that tab.

```
public class MyNavigationHandler
{
    _private readonly INavigationService _navigation;
   
    public MyNavigationHandler()
    {
        _navigation = PrismApplicationBase.Current.Container.Resolve<INavigationService>();
    }

    public async Task Navigate()
    {
        await _navigation.SelectTabAsync("Tab2Page");
        await _navigation.NavigateTo("SubPageOfTabTwoPage");
    }
}
```

And I call this logic like so:

```
var NavLogic = new MyNavigationHandler();
NavLogic.Navigate();
```

However, calling the two `_navigation` methods do nothing. My app just lands on the default tab. Am I doing this correctly? I've also noticed inconsistencies with the INavigationService that gets resolved. It appears to be different every time the class is created.

I'm doing this because I am trying to handle Push Notifications. There are several different types of push notifications that could take the user to several different pages and tabs in the app. I want to implement a strategy pattern where new push notification handlers can be easily added in the future.

Comment: "My app just lands on the default tab" doesn't sound like "do nothing", so I suspect you are attempting to test "too early" in app startup. If so, a better test would be to put that code on a button on a page of a different tab. There, does it work, or does it go back to default tab, or does it truly "do nothing"?

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate description of the behavior I am seeing is: When the app loads, my code is invoked, but no navigation occurs. The app opens up to the same page that was there when the app was backgrounded.

I did try your approach (tying the action to a button press) and I get the same result.

Comment: And you followed instructions at https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/working-with-tabbedpages.html? Most importantly, registered the tabs and pages with Prism?

Comment: Yes. These pages are eligible for navigation if the user manually taps through to them, but for some reason when I try to navigate programmatically like this it fails. The more I work with it I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the context with which the Navigation Service is resolved. I think that maybe the navigation IS actually succeeding, but it is succeeding in a different context than the selected tab. If that makes any sense

Comment: For instance, I created a static property on the Tab 2 ViewModel and set it to the instance of the INavigationService that is resolved in the constructor. And accessing that specific INavigationService instance solves my problem. But this is obviously horrible practice and not very maintainable

Comment: I don't use Prism, but in Dependency Injection, that symptom means INavigationService is not registered as a `Singleton`. In your X-Forms app startup, is there a line similar to `...Register<INavigationService>(...)`?  If so, it needs to be `...RegisterSingleton<INavigationService>(...)`.

Comment: ... Actually, there seems to be something different than I would expect in Prism. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/54672051/199364, though I don't know if that is up to date. I also see an unusual requirement of naming the injected parameter `navigationService`: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html#getting-the-navigation-service

Comment: ... Putting those two links together, I suspect that you have to use the parameter from the constructor. Otherwise, it is "unaware of the current View", and can't behave correctly. Maybe save `navigationService` in a public property of your viewmodels, so you can pass it in to your Navigate method.